# Rails has many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

In my Rails app, I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # user declaration
   has_many :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

I need to add another relation where each `Account` can be managed by multiple `AccountManagers`. However, `AccountManagers` themselves are also `Users` of this system (i.e. a `User` can both have an `Account` and manage another user's account).

I'm fairly new to Rails, and I know that I can just create another model called `AccountManagers`. I have a feeling that we don't NEED to make another model however; all the information contained within my proposed `AccountManagers` model is found in the `Users` model as well.

I've tried to add the following relationship to the `Account` model:

```
has_many :account_managers, through: :users, source: :users
```

where the `Account` has many managers, and each manager is declared from the `User` model. This doesn't work as the `AccountManagers` table doesn't exist (and the error in the view states that as well).

Is there a way to get this relationship to work?

Comment: try this "has_many :account_managers, through: :users, :class_name => "User", ,:foreign_key => "account_manager_id""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add another join table, say `account_managements` with columns and `user_id` and `account_id`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # user declaration
   has_many :accounts
   has_many :managed_accounts, :source => :account, :through => :account_managements 
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :account_managers, :source => :user, :through => :account_managements
end
```

and

```
class AccountManagement < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :account
end
```

Comment: It might just be me doing something wrong, but I'm now getting a `HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError` when I try to load my `new` route (all I'm doing is calling `Account.new`) in the `new` controller method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add another class `AccountManager`, You can add one more relation like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # user declaration
   has_many :account
   has_many :managed_accounts, :class_name => 'Account', :primary_key => :account_manager_id 
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :account_managers, : class_name => :User, :foreign_key => :account_manager_id
end
```

For this you will need to have `account_manager_id` in the `accounts` table.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I can see here is that a user has_many accounts, but in ur example, an account only has 1 user. Are u planning to have accounts with only 1 person in them?

In relational tables there are 2 main kinds of table designs.

## A. One to Many

U have a relationship where one thing has many of another thing, for instance: a Owner has many Cats. In this type of relationship the Cat table can point to the Owner table. Clearly the Owner cannot point to its cats because u would need to have a pointer for each cat. it would be something like

## Owners table

- cat_1
- cat_2
- cat_3

thats not convenient at all, since there is a maximum number of cats.

If on the other hand u have

## cats table

- owner_id

then each owner can have an unlimited amount of cats.

## More complex

After some time u get a request, some owners share a cat. u think about it a while and decide a cat can only belong to a max of 2 owners.

so u change the cat table.

## cats table

- owner_1
- owner_2

## B. Many to Many

If you want to be able to allow a cat to have any unlimited number of owners, or a owner to have an unlimited number of cats, u will need a third table. This table keeps a link from 1 cat to 1 owner. Each row defines this relationship. This table can be named either using the names of the other 2 tables: cat_owners or since this table defines a relationship u can give it a name that defines this relationship.

In this case the relationship is Ownership, people own cats. Its hard to say how the cats would define the relationship :)

This brings me to answer ur question finally. If u have a table that defines the link between a user and an account, I like the name Membership

## Membership

- user_id
- account_id

but as u just mentioned there are some users in an account who are Managers, u can add this flag to the membership table.

## Membership

- user_id
- account_id
- manager (true/false)

u could take it a step beyond that and change manager, to a role column, and then every user can have a different role in every account.

What if each user can have multiple roles in each account? Then u will need more tables

Rails doesnt mean u can skip understanding relational databases structure.